# Computation Program Not Running at 100% CPU Utilization

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, compiler, dll

I have a program which has a GUI and performs some very heavy mathematical computations for a couple of minutes and then outputs a result. When I try to directly interface it through its DLL's, it runs fine, but it doesn't run at 100% CPU usage like the GUI does. Why is this?

I understand the reason why computational heavy program might not run at 100% is due to I/O that it might be doing but this program doesn't do any, not even a single printf(). Files are being generated at the end of execution in both the GUI and DLL versions of the program. The interface program makes mulitple calls to the DLL during execution as well.

It is written in C, compiled using VS2008 CL compiler running in Release mode. Running on Intel i5 CPU with 4GB RAM (60% utilization average, never above 70%). When I set affinity to the process to one CPU (in this case, 1/4 "CPU's", 2 cores with 2 threads each), the GUI uses 100% of that dedicated CPU for about 2 min. My interfacing application uses anywhere from 60-80% CPU for about 5 minutes. I use Window's Performance Tab upon performing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHFT</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd>.

---EDIT---

I found that database calls (there are a few specific ones) are being preempted a lot for extended periods of time (usually 5 times slower). Using Process Explorer I was able to find out that each program uses exactly the same amount of CPU time -> leading to my conclusion about preemption. For anyone that doesn't know about this tool, download Process Explorer from SysInternals, very useful.

---EDIT---

I found that the GUI opens a single static connection to the database. While my interface doesn't do that, leading to opening and closing the connection thousands of times. Opening it once for the lifetime brought the CPU up to 100%.

Comment: Please tell us how many cores your CPU has, what tool you use for measurement of CPU utilization, and exactly what you mean by "not at 100%". Like, about how much?

Comment: I/O is more than printf(). Do you have enough memory?

Comment: Is it because the machine has multiple processor cores?  A single threaded application is only going to run on 1 processor.

Comment: Also: when you "directly interface it" are you constantly exchanging calls, or do you just tell it to start, and you wait until it stops?  Also: are you sure it is not saving anything to any file?  Also: please take a look at your memory utilization, as @ftr suggested.

Comment: Do you actually want the program to max out the processor or just be as fast as possible?

Comment: @RobZ Isn't maxing out the processor == fast as possible?

Comment: @skynorth - It depends but in general the percentage of the CPU utilization is not the best measure of if an algorithm has been optimized or not.

Comment: `I decided to not post this at Stack Overflow since it is a very open-ended question` In general, we don't like those here as well, don't make a habit of it. But I think your question is fine...

Comment: Are you sure the GUI isn't taking up the additional CPU itself?

Comment: Any news on this, skynorth? Did you profile it? What did you find out?

Comment: @MikeNakis It was crashing, just fixed it. There is a lot of code, getting close to finding out out what's slowing it down. However, I did find that the GUI spawns 2x more threads.

Comment: The GUI spawning more threads does not explain its 100% utilization unless a single thread somewhere, for some reason, yields its time slices.  Anyway, please keep us posted!

Comment: @MikeNakis I found out that when the program reads from the database (Access file), on average, it takes 5 times longer, and up to 10 times longer (measures in milliseconds). Will keep researching and post back.

Comment: @MikeNakis see update about preemption.

Comment: ;-D  I am glad I was of some help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Profile it!

It's the only way to know exactly what is happening and what is using what resources and where it's being limited at.

Comment: Any programs you recommend for Windows 7 64bit?

Comment: Quick&dirty profilng: debug a release build and break the process at random times. You'll gain an insight in what part of the code takes most of the time (statistically).

Comment: You might also want to look at [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx), which will show you what system calls are being used by a given process, if those might be the cause of waits and slowdowns.

Comment: @greyfade Thanks for suggestion, downloading. I figured out my program is very slow reading for the database (Access file). Hopefully this will help me out.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that your program is not the only one run by the OS. Each program has a priority assigned to it. You need to check that out and see if you can give you program a higher priority or reduce other running programs priorities when possible.

Answer (score 1):

Many things may be causing this. One possibility is that there is some desynchronization logic involved in calling the DLL and receiving results from it, and this logic somewhere relinquishes a timeslice. (`Sleep(0)` will not relinquish the remainder of your timeslice; `Sleep(1)` will.)

If by any chance you are using an awful lot of memory, there may be some swapping going on; that would slow things down A LOT. Try disabling your swapfile, and see if you get an out of memory error.  I use WinXP with 4GB of RAM and no swapfile, and my machine is FAST!  (Though I run the danger of running out of memory, but I keep track of that.)

And, of course, the possibility that it is writing to a file as it works is worth checking. Could it be that as it is thinking, it is writing its thoughts down in a log file?

Also, instead of using the Windows Task Manager for looking at CPU utilization, do yourself a favor and get [SysInternals' Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals). It is much, much better, and it will give you a lot more information about your processes, your DLLs, the handles that are open, etc.

Comment: Disabling your swap file doesn't prevent paging, it just forces the system to only page read-only pages (like program code) rather than having the option to page program code or least recently used data. See my comment [here](http://superuser.com/a/235732/16858) for an example of why.

Comment: @MarkBooth thank you for the comment. I was aware of these objections but I went ahead and I tried disabling my swapfile just to try it, and I did notice a performance increase. Also, I am pretty sure Windows XP is not swapping anything on my machine, for the very simple reason that there exists no swap file. In any case, I am open to reconsider, but I will have to first see substantially better evidence than just the words of some "MVP".

Comment: Disabling the page file does not disable paging. Also, many programs allocate lots of memory which they never use, if you have no page file then this has to stay in memory for the entire time the program is running. If you have a page file, this allocated memory (which is never referenced) can be paged out of physical memory leaving more physical memory for active data cache. Having more space for cache can easily result in a system *with* a page file running faster than one *without* one. Read [this excellent answer](http://serverfault.com/a/23684/25092) and its refs for more info.

Comment: Regarding the use of Sleep() in Windows program, I'd follow [this advice](http://www.flounder.com/badprogram.htm#Sleep).

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon what you are doing, maxing out the CPU is not the best way go and thus, the numbers you are getting back now might actually mean that things are running faster than they were before even though the processor is not maxed out. Even extremely complicated algorithms may not max out the CPU utilization and this can be a good thing as it means you can do other tasks while running the program.

Remember that when a program is running not all of the data may be in the processor cache and the time it takes to go out to the RAM (short from the processors perspective) or to other storage (e.g. hard drive, NAS, etc) (long from the processors perspective) is time that the processor can be running other tasks. Computers are very good at task switching and generally we use that to our advantage as well.

In terms of your program, doing anything with a GUI tends to be very slow as the GUI has to wait for the screen to repaint when updates are done and this can take an extremely long time to run from the processors standpoint. Most computationally heavy operations are written in such a way that they are decoupled from a GUI to ensure that they focus solely on their task and other tricks are used to report their status if they take awhile to run.

In terms of making your code as fast as possible, as Malfist noted [in their answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/128596/2471) profiling the code is your best bet and seeing what is running slow. Likewise, if possible making the algorithm run some parts in parallel will ensure it runs subjectively faster as it can take advantage of multiple cores on the processor. Additionally, you might want to write some very basic logging that notes when certain parts of the code is entered and exited (showing running time) and how many times certain operations are performed. These are typically given to you in a good profiler, but it can be a useful exercise to do on your own as well.